# Markov Chain Book Replacement

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

The question is given as:
Alice has 3 books, numbered 1 to 3, and picks a book
according to a probability distribution q, where q(k) > 0 for any k ∈ {1, 2, 3}.
Analyse the long-term behaviour of this chain; if at the end of the day she places it to the right-most position.

I'm not 100% Im doing right because it seems like its not going to any neat solution.
But my thought is maybe solving:

$Π123 = a3(Π123 + Π132 + Π312)$

$Π213 = a3(Π321 + Π231 + Π213)$

$Π132 = a2(Π123 + Π132 + Π213)$

$Π312 = a2(Π312 + Π213 + Π321)$

$Π231 = a1(Π123 + Π213 + Π231)$

$Π321 = a1(Π132 + Π312 + Π321)$

$1  = Π123 + Π132 + Π312 + Π213 + Π231 + Π321$

Ie. that with a probability $a3$ she picks book 3 (we don't know the actual probabilities) and if the books are in the order $123$ or $132$ or $312$ originally then when she places the 3rd book in the right-most position she will end up with the order $123$.
I did that for the rest of the options, but when I try to solve the simultaneous equations I get negative steady states, and I cant work out where my equations are incorrect.

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset maths

Comment: To me anyhow, "...picks a book according to a probability distribution $q$, where $q(k) > 0$ for any $k ∈ {1, 2, 3}.$" is nor clear. Can you clarify and set up the transition matrix for the chain?